# blockchain.info API response is coming with a big delay

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I'm using blockchain.info API on my shop. Everything was fine until about 2 weeks ago. The whole procedure and the issue is:
- When a customer place an order, a btc address is created and customer must send a certain amount of funds to this address.
- When funds are received on this wallet, blockchain.info is sending a response to my site that funds are paid.
- Automatic confirmation emails are sent to the customer when I receive this confirmation from blockchain.info.

About 10 days ago, I noticed that the "paid" reply comes with a big delay from blockchain.info. Log shows that there is a difference of about 4 hours between creating the invoice and paid responce. At the same time, I see that customer paid his order (3 confirmations) in 25 minutes (for example) after invoice was created.

As to mention, there were no such issue before. Something changed and I cant understand where.

Comment: You will likely need to contact their support, no one here is able to help you with this kind of company-specific issues